# Serial COM-connections 64bit versions

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port, windows-7-x64

I have a .net Application that writes text to a serial COM port, a POS reciept printer to be more exact. i am using the Rs232 class library to write and read to a serial device.

My problem is now with some clients that have updated their operatingsystem to WIN7 64bit version, have trouble to create a connection to the COM-port.

the com-port seemes to get occupied with some other process and that blocks my application to opening a new connection. so for my question, does anyone know how i can close all connections to a com port? or see whats blocking it? once again this seems to only to affect win7 and 64bit users.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to find the process that is hijacking the COM port. SysInternals' Handle utility should help you find it.  Other than that, I've seen the Telephony service grab a COM port on one of my machines.

Comment: Where can i find a SysInternals Handle utlity?

Comment: never mind, i found the http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

dont know what to look for tho /: